# Nginx force SSL (https) with cookie forwarding

Tags: session, cookies, ssl, nginx, url-rewriting

I am forcing `SSL` for a vhost in `nginx` with:

```
if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.mydomain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

The problem is if a user is logged in, with sessions (cookies), then opens a new tab and goes to `http://www.mydomain.com` this works and forwards to `https`, but the session is lost. I think because the cookie is not forwarded with the rewrite rule by nginx.

Is there a way to forward the cookies as well as run the rewrite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are unrelated to redirects. The server sending a "redirect" message has nothing to do with it. It's purely the web browser that decides whether or not to send a cookie on a given request. This is based on the attributes that have been set on the cookie, such as Path, Domain, Secure, and HttpOnly. I think you'll find that the attributes on your user's cookies are set in a way that tells the browser NOT to send them when accessing the new URL. This will definitely happen, for example, if you're redirecting to a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

A way out of the problem would be to separate the two concerns, maintaining the session and authentication. You could then leave the session id unprotected, only for maintaining the session, and use a separate cookie to check for the login state.

If a site uses HTTP mixed with HTTPS, the id would be transmitted plaintext in the URL